# Why my div height is smaller that is supposed to be?

Tags: css, height

`#mainCoridor` div's height is lower than 10% of screen on my monitor and I can't figure out why.

**Code:**

```css
body {
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: unset;
}

#mainCoridor {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="mainCoridor"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Any paddings or other elements taking up space?

Comment: When I ran it in JsBin with a simple HTML (`<body><div id="mainCoridor">!</div></body>`), it correctly took up 10% of the body (which took up 60% of the total.) Which is to say, it correctly took up 6% of the total height.

Comment: Size attribute values in percent (like `widht: 100%` and `height: 100%`) take up percentage of space of their parent (whatever the parent) not of the browser's viewport. You need to check each height/width in the nesting of your elements and check if there is a defined parent size an element can use. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas does have a good point...

Comment: @xKobalt In the future please also let OP be the one to update their post to include missing code; you've just taken a wild guess at what their HTML looks like here.

Comment: @TylerH, it's true that I spent a few minutes to make more evident the OP example, but  also it's true that new users should learn how to write posts in order to make them clearest as possible, so from now I'll keep this in mind too and I'll use more comments to achieve this. Thank you for the advice and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Your body is set to take up 60% of the viewport height.

The mainCoridor div is set to take up 10% of the body height (10% of 60% of the viewport height). See the image

If you want mainCoridor to take up 10% you need to set the body to 100vh.

Comment: After OP edited the question, `#mainCoridor { height: 10vh }` would make more sense... This will introduce the question: When? Landscape or Portrait or both? How about using VMIN?